# How to get the font colour css property from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code I'm using to get the background image of selected div from below code

```
let now = new Date().getHours() * 100 + new Date().getMinutes();
let times = [1015, 1100, 1145, 1230, 1315, 1700, 1750, 1800];
let ids = ['r1', 'r3', 'r5', 'r7', 'r9', 'r11', 'r13'];
let selected = ids[times.reduce((acc, curr, idx) => now >= curr ? idx : acc)];
if (selected) 
  document.getElementById(selected).parentElement.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/g.gif')";
```

How can I even change the font color of same div which is selected? I tried using this

```
if (selected) 
  document.getElementById(selected).parentElement.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/g.gif')";
document.getElementById(selected).parentElement.style.color = 'red';
```

but as I had expected, it didn't work out.

Here is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/BlueYeti/yy2nLpg2/3/

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your code should work, so long as `selected` gives a valid output and finds an element in the DOM. Could you edit the question to include a working snippet? Although note your question states you want to *get* the colour, yet you appear to be *setting* it

Comment: Getting or setting? You say get but you're setting the colour.

Comment: Well it was actually about setting. Here is the fiddle, could you please check it.  https://jsfiddle.net/BlueYeti/yy2nLpg2/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try using jquery something like.

```
To colour and font-size :-

$( '#id option:selected' ).css({ 'color': 'red', 'font-size': '100%' });

To background image:-

var imageUrl = "images/g.gif";
$( '#id option:selected' ).css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
```

Comment: well it is bit complicated as I have different id as r11, r12 and so on . so have no idea where to put all this. Here is the fiddle could you please check it.   https://jsfiddle.net/BlueYeti/yy2nLpg2/3/